# Initial vale problem: existence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does the initial-value problem $d y / d x=x / y$, $y(0)=0$ have a solution?

My answer of this quesstion is that equation, no have solution, because is not defined and also by the theorem of existence and unicity, that is not continous in 0.

My question is: Exist any justification or proof more formal to this question?

Thanks

Comment: What about $y(x) = x$?

Comment: Or $y(x)=-x{}$?

Comment: In the book that the part a), the part b) is the question in this page, the book is differential equation of Zill,  separable equation sección.

Comment: The part of the solution of this book written: no have solution because is indefined, but i think that is not formal.

Answer (score 3):

Before you talk about solutions to an equation, you should always clarify what you mean by a solution. The differential equation
$$
(1) \quad y'(x)=\frac{x}{y(x)}
$$
is of the form $y'(x)=f(x,y(x))$ with $f(x,y)=x/y$, and the natural domain of $f$ is
$$
D:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid y \not=0\}.
$$
A usual solution concept is, that a solution of $(1)$ is a differentiable function $y:I \to \mathbb{R}$ on an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
{\rm Graph}~ y = \{(x,y(x))\mid x\in I\} \subseteq D \quad \text{and} \quad \forall x \in I: ~ y'(x)=f(x,y(x)).
$$
With this definition of solutions the IVP
$$
(2) \quad y'(x)=\frac{x}{y(x)}, ~~ y(0)=0
$$
has no solution since $(0,0) \notin D$.

On the other hand for such singular differential equations you can choose different solution concepts. In your case for example:

$y:I \to \mathbb{R}$ is a solution of (1) if it is differentiable and $y'(x)y(x)=x$ ($\iff (\frac{d}{dx}y^2)(x)=\frac{d}{dx}x^2$) for all $x \in I$.

With this definition of solutions you find that solutions of (2) satisfy $y(x)^2=x^2$ and you get the solutions $y:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$,  $y(x)=x$ or $y(x)=-x$, respectively, as noted in the comments.

Note that the solution concept is crucial for almost all equations. If you consider $a^2=-1$ the solution set depends on your solution concept (real or complex numbers, or whatever).